# Customer not logging in though they registered successfully and details saved in db

Tags: magento2.2.8, customer-registration

After register with new account, `customer_entity` table populated with the user details. But in frontend the user not logged in.

When we clear the browser cookies, then the user can able to register and login successfully. After some time this issue again occurring.

```
form_key available in the registration phtml file.
```

cookie path and cookie domain also set correctly in the backend.

Still we are facing this issue, Anybody having idea over here?